# overlay on clickable region - CSS

Tags: html, css

Is there a way I can have a partially transparent image (or anything really) overlay a clickable region using XHTML and CSS?

Comment: Why not have the overlay clickable?

Comment: @Andre your suggestion doesn't work if the overlay is only overlaying part of the clickable region (at least not if you have a complex clickable region with something like an HTML5 video element).

Comment: It would be awesome if I could do this: `foreground:#4297cc url('overlay.png');` :)

Comment: Which browsers you need to support?

Comment: @thirtydot If you know of a solution that works in only one browser I still would love to here it! Although the more support the better.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> @thirtydot If you know of a solution
>   that works in only one browser I still
>   would love to here it! Although the
>   more support the better.

You can use [`pointer-events: none`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/pointer-events).

Browser support: http://caniuse.com/pointer-events (works everywhere except IE10 and older)

http://jsfiddle.net/QC5Yw/

Comment: The attribute is new to me. Thanks for teaching me something new!

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the overlay and background in a clickable div, and set the opacity attribute of the overlay to something less than 1.

http://www.w3schools.com/Css/css_image_transparency.asp

Comment: if the overlay is only overlaying part of the content then the content that is not underneath the overlay will look partially transparent, and this is not what I want.

Comment: He didn't say to make the clickable div tanslucent; he said to make the overlay **inside** the div translucent, therefore showing the overlay and making everything clickable. However, this still won't work with a <video> tag, or a Java/Flash embed.

Answer (score -1):

No, the top z-index element will have the focus. But you can create another transparent top layer over the overlay layer, this one will be clickable. So:

```
z-index:1  Content element
z-index:2  Mask/Overlay element
z-index:3  Click element
```

That's because the browser cannot distinguish where your PNG is transparent. It just takes it as an image and will not pass the focus through if there are transparent pixels in it.
Thats why you can put a completely empty div with fixed with and height and it will be clickable.

Comment: As I said to @Andre your suggestion doesn't work if the overlay is only overlaying part of the clickable region (at least not if you have a complex clickable region with something like an HTML5 video element).

Comment: Well if the clickable area is a rectangle and is always in the same place than i don't see the problem. But if you want another shaped area or you want it to move throughout the movie, than yes, you are right.