# How to put div background on top of it's content

Tags: html, css

So i have one div and inside i have img tag. SO what i would like to do is put that div background on top of img, i know i could use another div with absolute position to do that but maybe it's possible to do it with only 1 div?

This is my code:

```
<div id="container">
   <img src="image.jpg" />
</div>
```

**EDIT** Sorry for explaining it all wrong, but i want to background over the image, and from what i can see right now it's not possible without extra div.

Comment: What do you mean by putting the div background on top? Wouldn't that cover up the image?

Comment: No it wouldn't since it would be transperent

Comment: There is no "front-ground' style for divs.  You will need another div.

Comment: So, if I understand you correctly, the div has a background image that is tranparent or has some portion that is transparent and you want that to appear above or over the image that is inside the div? Well, why not reverse the two images? That is, make the background the image and the image the background? I too am missing something here.

Comment: You might be able to use pointer-events:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6233872/overlay-on-clickable-region-css

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply put, you can't with that code.
The best you could do is use some positioning and z-index properties within a single div.

```
<div id="container">
   <div id="cover"></div>
   <img src="image.jpg" />
</div>
```

Then use CSS to move the `cover` div above the image.

Answer (score 0):

You can use css to attach the background for div like

```
background: url(images/myimage.png) no-repeat center top;
```

Comment: He wants the background image to be on top of the content in the div.

Comment: Then he should have mentioned over or overlapped.