# How to put image div container over another div container?

Tags: css, image, html, containers, layer

I'm new to wordpress and website building. Just bought a theme and faced an issue.

I want to put my image over accordion div container. How I can do that? My theme has content building option, but as far as I know it doesn't support creating layers feature (nor any other content builder plugins, like [this](http://codecanyon.net/item/visual-composer-for-wordpress/242431?WT.ac=search_thumb&WT.seg_1=search_thumb&WT.z_author=mixey) or [this](http://codecanyon.net/item/ether-content-builder-wordpress-plugin/1690784?WT.ac=search_thumb&WT.seg_1=search_thumb&WT.z_author=pordesign)

I would really appreciate any kind of help!

Comment: My page that I need to edit: http://podstrigis.com/%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%81-%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82/

Comment: That's what I want to make my page look like -

http://i.imgur.com/LuqvdYQ.jpg

Answer (score 0):

If you find a way to customize the CSS, this should do the trick:

```
.column.one {
  position: absolute;
  z-index:  2;
}
```

The property `position:absolute` allows you to position the image freely using the CSS properties `top`, `left`, `right` and `bottom`.

`z-index:2` makes sure, that the image is in front of the accordion.

*Edit:*

Turns out that there is one more problem: since the image overlaps the accordion, the overlapped areas are not clickable anymore. To solve this problem, you can use the CSS property `pointer-events:none`. But beware! This is not supported by IE and Opera. You may need to find a workaround for these browsers.

- Browser Compatibility Table: http://caniuse.com/pointer-events
- Article about the Property: http://www.sitepoint.com/css3-pointer-events/

Comment: Thanks! But that doesn't work in a way it should. The image overrides my accordion and the top part of it is not clickable

Comment: I was just about to point you to [this answer to a related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6233872/overlay-on-clickable-region-css) which says that `pointer-events:none` would be a good way to go. But then I checked your site again and discovered that you found this property on your own. :-)